# How to use arrow notation (->) to create a protected method?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, protected, access-modifiers

When we write following code

```
Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5).filter(i -> (i%2 == 0)).map( i -> i*i );
```

the expression `i -> (i%2 == 0)` or `i -> i*i` will turn into a **private** method.

In my usecase, one of the junit test is written to ensure no method is private (yaah, that’s mandated), and it fails for these lambda expression.

Can someone suggest something wherein I don't have to change junit to add some exclusion for lambda expressions, but make these expression to make a **protected** method internally?

Comment: Your test is insane, and you should get rid of it.

Comment: If that's your requirement, define the methods explicitly, and make them protected. But, like SLaks says, this is a frankly insane requirement.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say that the lambda "turns into a private method". If it "turns into" anything it's an instance of `Function` or something, and those methods are public. I mean, if it turned into a private method, how would `filter` and `map` be able to invoke them?

Comment: @aioobe: He means that the compiler generates a private method.

Comment: Ok. I see. For non-capturing lambdas the compiler may desugar it to static method. Got it. I think @Nikem has the best workaround.

Comment: Besides the nonsense of such a requirement, the unit test should skip *synthetic* methods, as there might be other constructs for which the compiler generates `private` methods as well. Don’t define constraints for things outside your control.

Comment: @Holger, completely agree with you, i removed check for those auto generated methods from my test cases. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
protected static boolean isEvent(int i){
  return i %2 == 0
}

ints.stream().filter(MyClass::isEvent)
```

Comment: That is really nice workaround but it **kills** the whole notion of arrow notation. :)

Is there any way to not replace arrow and still get the protected method ?

Comment: Method references are absolutely legal and idiomatic way to use existing methods instead of lambda. Other way around - not that often, yes :)

Comment: I buy your solution. :)